# How to allow or deny remote connections in Python's SocketServer?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, socketserver

I'm creating an extremely simple [Vega](https://vega.github.io/vega/) visualization viewer: it's a [one file module](https://github.com/diana-hep/vegascope/blob/master/vegascope.py) that serves a base HTML page containing just the Vega graphic and an HTML5 `EventSource` of updates. The user (me) is working in a Python shell through ssh, creates an object representing the viewer, which prints its IP and port for the user to paste into their (my) web browser. This HTTP server doesn't serve files or take input from clients, so I don't see any security concerns.

The part I'm unsure of is how to set `(host, port)` such that my web browser can find the HTTP server running in the remote Python. I've been experimenting all afternoon, and I don't know if I'm misunderstanding what's *supposed* to happen or if the servers I use have changed their access policies.

Here's a minimal example:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer((host, port), Handler)
print(httpd.server_address)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

If I'm running this locally and want to ensure that outside viewers *cannot* access it, do I set `host` to `"127.0.0.1"` because that means a client would have to access it *as* 127.0.0.1, which can only happen locally? In this case, `port` can be `0` to get any open port.

If I'm running this remotely want to to ensure that outside viewers *can* access it, do I set `host` to `""` or `"0.0.0.0"` because that means that a client can access it as any address that makes its way to the server? In this case, I might not be able to set `port` to `0` because many of those ports might be blocked, or is the OS smarter about this?

Basically, how is access control in Python's SocketServer *supposed* to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basic TCP. Nothing to do with Python.

If you listen at 127.0.0.1, only clients running in the same host can connect.

If you listen at 0.0.0.0, anybody can connect, firewalls permitting.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know, although I couldn't be sure that this Python library wasn't using the values differently than raw sockets calls in C would. How about ports? Does `0` pick from the ports available to the outside world or just any port?