# Handle ConnectionResetError & BrokenPipeError python http server

Tags: python, exception, remote-server, http.server

New to python serves outside of a framework. Need a simple server to run and load few pdf files forever.

Running a server in remote using http.server

```
PORT = 8000

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except SocketError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.ECONNRESET:
            raise
        pass  # Don't know what to do here.
```

Testing at `localhost` is working fine.
At remote, the server stops randomly. Upon checking logs I receive 2 errors frequently

Happens when client closes browser when a file is being loaded

```
self._sock.sendall(b)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

No idea what triggers this:

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

How to handle these ? Do I need to add wait time or sleep time to avoid. Looking for anyhelp.

Comment: Possible duplicate [how-to-allow-or-deny-remote-connections-in-pythons-socketserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49268568/how-to-allow-or-deny-remote-connections-in-pythons-socketserver)

Comment: @MohamadGhaithAlzin Don't think so. I don't want to deny/allow any remote. I want to handle these occurring exceptions properly so that server doesn't die in any case.